# How to stop a request from being directed to a node until the heartbeat is up?

Tags: hazelcast, elastic-load-balancer

In a load balanced cluster, how to avoid a request from being sent to a node that is still starting and initializing its cache and heartbeat is not yet up and running. I have tried all the methods in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_hcheck.html. But did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably have to build your own little healthcheck into the application and call it from the mod_proxy config.

Comment: It is already built. But still the healthcheck does not hit those services. How to atleast monitor to see if healthcheck is really working?